# Rename classes.jar file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

By default android studio generated classes.jar in build file, but i need it as like project name. How to rename by default in project file or android studio configuration.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to generate Xamarin binding project, when add two binding library dll to an application, it will not complied and showing error like classes.jar file conflicting.